# Javascript Validate number, nonrepeating, nonsquential

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to validate an input.

The input must be numeric, 9-digits long.

We need to prevent 000000000, 111111111, 222222222, 123456789, 234567890, 098765432, 987654321, 010101010, 121212121, 000000001, 000000010 and so on type inputs.

The only thing I can think of is testing each possibility. Obviously that would be a monstrous amount of code, or a regex like:

```
var input="111111111";
var regex = /000000000|11111111|222222222|123456789|234567890|098765432|987654321|010101010|121212121|00000001|000000010/; // and so on and so on and so on.......
var found = input.match(regex);

console.log(found);
```

Does anybody have a better way to do this?

Comment: What do these numbers represent?

Comment: Customer Account number, not verifiable from a database, they are from another network.

Comment: so basically each digit 0->9 can show up at most once, and you don't want any "neighbor" digits to actually be neighbors, e.g. `32` would be ok but `23` is bad? With those rules, you're going to have a pretty small pool of numbers available. even just the non-repeating will give you at most 362,880 variations.

Comment: Looks like you're trying to put some restrictions on a password to me. You need to define the sequences you want to prevent. 'and so on' doesn't mean much... Plus you might be better off with a custom function for the sequential digits one.

Comment: Can you better characterize the invalid numbers besides a short list and "and so on type inputs"?

Comment: @MarcB 32 and 23 would be ok, as long as the whole string is not 123456789, 876238723 would be ok. We need to prevent junk data from being entered to bypass the validation better. the input should not be perfectly sequential, all the same, and one offs like 000000001 or 000000050 or 777777778

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid repeated sequences and numbers like 111811111 with:

```
\b(?!(?:(?=(\d))((\d+)\3)\2*\1|(\d{3})\4{2}|(?=\d*(\d)(?!\5)(\d))(?:\5*\6\5*|\6*\5\6*))\b)\d{9}\b
```

You can test: 123456789, 012345678, 876543210 etc.

with:

```
if ( parseInt(s) + parseInt(s.split("").reverse().join("")) % 111111111 == 0 )
```

Comment: Looks as close to what I want as its going to get. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about parsing the single numbers into a list of integers. Then you could test more easily for general cases like "all the same number", "ascending list", "descending list", "alternating numbers" and so on.

That's of course assuming you don't want to use RegExs for the sake of using them.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a regex.